# Are ternary operators in ternary operatory possible

Tags: javascript, node.js, conditional-operator

Why does this line doesnt work

```js
        x > highNum ? highNum = x : y > highNum ? highNum = y : highNum = highNum
```

In this case this line is in a loop and x and y is different everytime. I tried to find the highest number at the end and thought this would work.
In my mind this reads as:
If x is higher than high num
highnum should get assigned the value of x
if not.
is y bigger?
if yes y should be the new highnum.
if not.
dont change high num

Comment: If you're not insistent on using ternary operators, `highnum = Math.max(x, y, highNum)` is the best way to do this.

Comment: *"doesn't work"* is not such a clear problem description. Describe what goes wrong. Better even, include a concrete example in a runnable snippet, highlighting the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

##### short answer:

Yes, they are.

##### long answer:

Yes, but you should be concerned about readability too. You code does exactly what you are expecting it to do, but other devs (and maybe you in the future), could have a problem understanding that, so I'd strongly advice you to never use nested ternary operators, and only use them when it makes more sense then a simple if else statement.
And if even after all this you still wanna use it, at least add a comment explaining what it does. ex:

```js
  let highNum
  for(let line of lines){
     const {x, y} = line; 
     // use bubble sort to find the highest number
     x > highNum ? highNum = x : y > highNum ? highNum = y : highNum = highNum
  }
```

edit: Also, this is also not correctly finding the highest number, as said by "trincot"

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but you'll require brackets, mostly for readability:

```js
(x > highNum) ? (highNum = x) : ((y > highNum) ? (highNum = y) : (highNum = highNum));
```

In your case, it seems you're better off splitting it into multiple statements to prevent confusion:

```js
if (x > highNum) {
    highNum = x;
} else if (y > highNum) {
    highNum = y;
}
```

*although that doesn't fit in a single expression, but perhaps that's a sign of your code getting a bit too complex/unreadable.*

If you're solely looking for the highest number, perhaps [Math.max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) is all you need, i.e. `Math.max(x, y, highNum)`.

Comment: Yeah you are probably right. Just curious if this is possible. Could use for some funny oneliner

Comment: Technically you can. You could use `x > highNum ? x : (y > highNum ? y : highNum)` to get the highest value, and slap `highNum = (...)` around it if you also want to set the variable. Funny oneliners can be fun, but usually frowned upon in proper projects. _Hard to understand, test and maintain and such._

Answer (score 3):

There is a potential high value that you could miss: when `x > highNum`, but also `y > x`, you will not see that `y` is really the highest, as the expression will already have decided that `highNum` should get the value of `x`.

You can do this quite simple with `Math.max`:

```
highNum = Math.max(x, y, highNum);
```

Answer (score 2):

> If x is higher than high num highnum should get assigned the value of x if not. is y bigger? if yes y should be the new highnum. if not. dont change high num

That would be:

```
highNum = (x > highNum) ? x : ((y > highNum) ? y : highNum)
           [condition] ?[true]:         [false]
                              ([condition] ? [true] : [false]) // Evaluated if the first condition was false
```

The structure is `variable = [condition] ? [value for true] : [value for false]`

And you can have a nested ternary instead of a `[value]` using additional parenthesis.

This is the same as:

```
if(x > highNum) {
  highNum = x
} else if(y > highNum) {
  highNum = y
} else {
  highNum = highNum // Quite useless... That is for explanation purpose ;)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to consider `y>x` instance as well.

`highNum = (x > y) ? (x > highNum ? x : highNum) :(y > highNum ? y : highNum);`

The above is equal to the below:

```
if (x>y) {
    if (x>highNum) {
        highNum = x;
    } else {
        highNum = highNum;
    }
} else { //covers both instances of y>x and x=y
    if (y>highNum) {
        highNum = y;
    } else {
        highNum = highNum;
    }
}
```